# How to copy a CakePHP Entity

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm writing a method that copies an object. Instead of manually setting each property manually, it would be more robust to just loop over the original object's properties...

```
//Booo
$new->name = $old->name;
$new->color = $old->color;
...

//Oh yeah...
foreach ($old as $prop=>$val){
    $new->$prop = $val;
}
unset $new->id;
```

It appears that CakePHP entities cannot be iterated over in this way. I tried using `$old->toArray()`, which basically works... but has the drawback of converting all the associations to arrays also, which is screwing this up for me down stream.

How do I loop over the $old properties without converting all the data types?

**Update**: 
Mark brought to my attention the existence of a [`__clone()`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Database.Expression.QueryExpression.html#___clone) method. Sounds like it does exactly what I need but I'm still figuring out how to use it.

Comment: If you are trying to copy all the properties on the object, you might want to use `clone`.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I wasn't able to find that in the docs... Will it do associations too? Like cascading clone?

Comment: @MarkStory I updated the title of the question to more accurately reflect what I'm trying to do. Your `__clone()` tip sounds spot on... want to submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $entity->visualProperties()

```
foreach($old->visualProperties() as $property) {
    if($new->has($property))
        $new->set($property, $old->get($property));
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this for a while, and discovering there is no __clone() function for entities, at least in 3.8, I have worked out how to do it, with the hint from DouglasSantos :

```
//Find out the entity classname
$classname = get_class($entity);

//Instanciate a new object of that class    
$clone = new $classname;

//Use visibleProperties to clone it
foreach($entity->visibleProperties() as $property)
    if($clone->has($property))
    $clone->set($property, $entity->get($property));
```

Of course you could combine the first 2 lines into one line, but I have split it out for clarity.

UPDATE: I have discovered if you use the has->($property) check it will skip many of the fields. So the corrected answer is :

```
//Find out the entity classname
$classname = get_class($entity);

//Instanciate a new object of that class    
$clone = new $classname;

//Use visibleProperties to clone it
foreach($entity->visibleProperties() as $property)
    $clone->$property = $entity->$property;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually much easier to use the Table Object:

```
// Assuming your model is called "Documents"
// If you are in the Controller, you can just use `$this->Documents`
   instead of fetching the Table from the Registry
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
$table = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Documents');

// newEntity() creates a new Entity from an array of data
$documentCopy = $table->newEntity(
    // extract() extracts the given properties as an associative array
    $document->extract(
        // getVisible() will get all visible properties as an array
        $document->getVisible()
    )
);
```